# Register for button events using cefsharp [chromium web browser engine]

Tags: .net, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, cefsharp.offscreen

I want to know when ever any user clicks on a particular button, presently i am able to get the events such as whenever user clicks on anywhere on window by using this

```
public void OnFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"window.onclick = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); bound.onClicked(e.target.outerHTML); }")
    }
}
```

in the same i want to listen for the buttons and other controls etc.,

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/demo/javascriptbinding contains a working example